# Android Drawer - Navigating to Multiple Fragments using Navigation.findNavController()

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment, drawer

I do not know if I am doing this right.
I use a Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio and successfully browsing 3 menu option.
What I did is for all menu I added if else what the next fragment will be shown.
I feel like this kind of approach is kind of hard specially I need to add more menu.

Is their a better way for navigating fragments. Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String title =  getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_status))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_status_to_home_fragment);
            } else if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_gallery))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_galley_to_home_fragment);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.nav_status:
            if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_home))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_home_to_status_fragment);
            } else if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_gallery))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_galley_to_status_fragment);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_home))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_home_to_gallery_fragment);
            } else if(title.equals(getString(R.string.title_status))) {
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_status_to_gallery_fragment);
            }
            break;
    }

    item.setChecked(true);
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    return true;
}
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.ddc.qvac.framents.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_status_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_status" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_gallery_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_gallery" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.ddc.qvac.framents.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_galley_to_home_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_galley_to_status_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_status" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_status"
        android:name="com.ddc.qvac.framents.StatusFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_status"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_status">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_status_to_home_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_status_to_gallery_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_gallery" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 2):

use same id for:

- `id` that defined in fragment tag in navigation xml file
- `id` that defined in menu xml file

in your `mobile_navigation.xml` file you are using `"@+id/nav_home"` for home fragment. in your menu.xml file make id of home  menu as `"@+id/nav_home"`

if both ids are same in menu file and navigation file, it will automatically navigate to the fragment. we don't need to do any boilerplate code.

Comment: Thank you. IT WORKS! I don't know why I didn't think of that.